# How do I convert spatial points to neighbours list in R?

Tags: r, statistics, spatial, correlation, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to convert some spatial points to a neighbour list in R. I have a list of individual animal species occurrences worldwide, each one with a single value of latitude and longitude. As I am trying to conduct a statistical analysis of a possible spatial autocorrelation, I would need to create an object class nb (neighbour list), but I do not know how to do this conversion in R.

My data looks like:

```
SPECIES   LATITUDE    LONGITUDE
species A     -85           134
species B      34             2
species B      42             3
species B      45             5
species C      -2            80
species C      -5            79
(...)
```

The dataset also contains other columns with the values of certain variables, but I think this is not important for my purpose.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262887/converting-spatial-points-to-neighbours-list-using-r) can help

Comment: This tutorial may help: http://rspatial.org/analysis/rst/3-spauto.html

Comment: I tried those links before, but I could not find anything useful for my case

Comment: If your data is really global you might have to think a bit more carefully about how you construct your neighbour list. I guess you want neighbours to cross the dateline at -180/+180 degrees longitude? I'm not sure this will happen by default with planar geometric packages which are the most common in R. I would guess that they treat you lon,lat coordinates as if they live in the flat rectangle [-180,180]x[-90,90]. It might be the case that everything is handled correctly, but you should double check that you really get what you expect.

Comment: Yes, I have worldwide values of coordinates, and I would need also to include neighbours crossing the dateline at -180/+180 of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `spdep` have different methods to calculate neighbors list. It's better to first convert your data frame to a spatial object. That will ensure that the coordinates will be correctly interpreted.

```
dataSp <- read.table( text = '
  SPECIES   LATITUDE    LONGITUDE
  speciesA     -85           134
  speciesB      34             2
  speciesB      42             3
  speciesB      45             5
  speciesC      -2            80
  speciesC      -5            79',
  header = TRUE )

library(spdep)

coordinates(dataSp) <- ~ LONGITUDE + LATITUDE
```

Neighbors are usually computed from polygons, since shared boundaries is the main criteria. You can generate polygons using techniques like Voronoi and Thiessen, but it's not necessary. Instead of using boundaries, you can use k nearest as criteria:

```
knea <- knearneigh(coordinates(dataSp), longlat = TRUE)
neib <- knn2nb(knea)
```

Or use distance range:

```
neib <- dnearneigh(coordinates(dataSp), 0, 10, longlat = TRUE)
```

Comment: When I try to convert my data frame to spatial object I receive this error: Error in na.fail.default(list(LONGITUDE = c(155, 155, 150, -72, -74, -57,  : 
  missing values in object

Comment: I am completely sure that there are no NAs in the coordinates (there are missing values in other columns, but not in latitude and longitude). In fact, I apllied na.omit(dataSp), but the error persists when trying the spatial conversion. What could not be working?

Comment: NAs outside the coordinate columns wouldn't generate that error. Check with `anyNA(dataSp[c('LONGITUDE', 'LATITUDE')])`. If any, find the rows: `dataSp[is.na(dataSp[c('LONGITUDE', 'LATITUDE')]),]`. It also can be the case that there is some coordinate with an invalid value; check with `range(dataSp[...`. If you can't figure out how to solve, post a new question specific for that, with a sample of your data that includes at least some of these rows. SO exist to help, but try to guess the problem in the comments section is not a good way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem. But now, when I try to create the neighbours list, I obtain another error because I have duplicate points. How could I solve this?

Comment: Depending on the type of analysis you will perform later: a) Create an object with only the coordinates and use unique() to remove the duplicates; use an location id column to link the spatial object to your species data. b) subset your data by species and create a neighbor list for each one.

Comment: Very nice answer. However, I don't see why would you use the Delaunay triangulation for that. Being a triangulation, it produces a number of polygons that is quite different from the initial number of points. Maybe the Voronoi diagram, confined within some finite region would do. The other methods produce neighbors lists with the right size.

Comment: You're right, Voronoi is better in this case. It's a force of habit, I use Delaunay for other things.